# Prime factor decomposition not working for numbers with repeated factors

Tags: python, prime-factoring

In this code, the user has to input an interval, and the program has to calculate the prime factor decomposition for each number in this interval.

However, I am unable to print the correct prime factor decomposition for numbers that have repeated factors, such as 4, 8 and 9.

I tried to use a while loop, but I am unable to use it correctly and my code just runs nonstop.

**Problem requirement:** Find the prime factorization of all integers in a given interval [a,b].

**Expected output for range(3,10):**

```
3=3
4=2*2
5=5
6=2*3
7=7
8=2*2*2
9=3*3
10=2*5
```

**My code:**

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
j = [] #list for prime numbers
lst = [] #list for factors for numbers in range(a,b)


# prime numbers
for number in range(2, b+1):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        j.append(number)

#factors
for c in range(a, b+1):
    lst = []
    for i in j:
        k = c % i
        if k == 0:
            lst.append(i)

    print(f'{c}=', end='')
    print(*lst, sep='*')
```

**My Code Output for range (3,10):**

```
3=3
4=2
5=5
6=2*3
7=7
8=2
9=3
10=2*5
```

I appreciate any feedback I can get, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. I edited your post to fit our question guidelines in [ask]. Check out that page for yourself if you'd like some tips.

Comment: Beside the point, but you can make this code a lot clearer with variable names. I'd rename `j` -> `primes`, `lst` -> `factors`, and `for i in j` -> `for prime in primes`. Also, you don't need to set `lst = []` at the top if you're just going to overwrite it in the loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone!! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close.  Instead of checking `c % i` just once, you have to loop until that is no longer 0.

```
#factors
for c in range(a, b+1):
    print(f'{c}=', end='')
    lst = []
    for i in j:
        while i <= c and c % i == 0:
            c //= i
            lst.append(i)

    print(*lst, sep='*')
```

Note that I had to move the `print` of `c` to the top of the loop, because I'm modifying `c` within the loop.  I didn't notice that until I did a test run.